# Commerce Kickstart - items won't float side by side

Tags: commerce

I'm developing a store using the new Commerce Kickstart 2.  All of a sudden my items in the store are floating one on top of the other instead of items within the same collection floating side by side. For example I have multiple headings of "Notebook Computers" above each notebook computer product and they all float one on top of the other all the way down the page instead of One header and all the products floating side by side.

I took my CSS back to the default and it didn't make a difference.  Has anyone else come across this? I'm not sure if a module I may have installed caused this or a setting within the view may have caused this.  I'm hoping someone else has come across this.
Thanks!
Candace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAAAh!  The answer is to shut down the site, shut down localhost, and re-start everything back up again.  It must have been a memory issue!